# Sort by hierarchyid in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a hierarchyid column defined on a table in SQL Server 2008

Let us say that in the first row, the hierarchyid is '/1/7/1/'

Let us say that in the second row, the hierarchyid is '/1/10/1/'

If I `sort by hierarchyid ASC` , then I will see the second row, and then the first row. (The sorting will be sort by String, and '10'<'7')

However I have (for compatability reasons with a different system) a wish to see the first row first, and then the second row (I.e. sort by int, and 7<10)

I have solved the problem, by defining a second hierarchyid column, and then setting it to be the same as the first hierarchyid column, but replacing all inside slashes with dots, and then doing a sort by this.

I just wondered if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a [hierarchyid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)?. Seams to work as expected. Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7cfe/2).

Comment: You're right (great link by the way). I will have to check what I did wrong... (I am using hierarchyID but maybe there's some other factor)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a fairly old question, but it was first result in Google so thought I'd add an actual answer in case someone else comes across this. Without seeing the SQL being used it's hard to be 100% but I suspect that the OP is returning the hierarchy Id as a string and sorting on that rather than sorting on the hierarchy id itself:

EG..

```
declare @results table (Id int, Hierarchy hierarchyId)

-- :
-- Add your data here
-- :

-- This will not work as it's ordering a string
select Id, Hierarchy.ToString() as SortOrder from @results order by SortOrder

-- This will work as it's ordering the hierarchy id
select Id, Hierarchy.ToString() as SortOrder from @results order by Hierarchy
```

Comment: Thank you Andy for your suggestion. I think you may very well be right, as I have tried to resurrect my pre-production code and it could have been the following `select * from ...,HIERARCHY.ToString() as HIERARCHY,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HIERARCHY order by HIERARCHY) AS RowNumber FROM MyTable` and your answer would then explain that 'order by HIERARCHY' was using not the original field but the .ToString().

Comment: If this was my original code, then my original question was not clear at all. But since this was such a long time ago, I am not quite sure why I asked my question in the way that I did. Anyway, my non-elegant solution has been in production for a long time now, and I am not - in the near future - working on this section of the code.  I am sorry I haven't got the resources at the moment to work on this, and to grade your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to isolate whats between the two "/" and order by it. 
you can use this function: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/nthindex/

to get the nth Index on a string, so

```
declare @aux_str varchar(50)
set @aux_str='/1/7/3/'

select dbo.fnNthIndex(@aux_str,'/',2)
```

returns 3. Them you have to find out the position of the third "/" and get what's between it.

Its not hard, but its quite a lot of work

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. This solution assumes that the hierarchyID is always three levels. In my question I wanted to present the problem as simply as possible, but the hierarchyID can be any number of levels.

Comment: your example is not hierarchyId, its varchar data type!